# Firebase Admin SDK: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a web app using webpack that utilizes Firestore.
When I run my app, I receive this error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request'`

I had a major issue with polyfills earlier. I tried to solve it by using babel and also 'resolve.fallback' but to be honest, this is my first day developing in this environment and I'm completely clueless as to which one to use..

**My package.json:**

```html
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel src -d lib", // running this says the file compiled successfully, but how do I run the app?
    "app": "webpack" // running this runs my app, but returns the error mentioned
  },
}
```

**My webpack.config.js:**

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      "fs": false,
      "tls": false,
      "net": false,
      "path": false,
      "zlib": false,
      "http": false,
      "https": false,
      "stream": false,
      "crypto": false,
      "crypto-browserify": false,
      "url": require.resolve("url"),
      "os": false,
      "os-browserify": false,
      "querystring": false,
      "buffer": false,
      "constants": false,
      "child_process": false
    },
},
  watch: true
};
```

**The full error:**

```html
WARNING in ./node_modules/retry-request/index.js 76:21-39
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'request' in '<...>/public/node_modules/retry-request'
 @ ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/streamingCalls/streaming.js 23:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/google-gax/build/src/fallback.js 33:20-57 54:18-55
 @ ./node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/index.js 476:38-59 497:95-121 1511:15-43 468:46-86 1214:21-74
 @ ./node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firestore/index.js 23:18-52
 @ ./src/index.js 2:25-60
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can resole it in way you already do. Just add `"request": false` in `fallback` object